# Getting image from firebase using glide and set into recycler view but image not load

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-glide

Getting image from fire base using glide and set into recycler view but image not load

```
upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
Glide.with(mContext).load(uploadCurrent.getFilePathUri()).into(holder.mimageView);
holder.textViewname.setText(uploadCurrent.getProductName());
holder.textViewcontact.setText(uploadCurrent.getContactNumber());
holder.textViewprice.setText(uploadCurrent.getPrice());
```

Comment: can you tell me glide code to get image

Comment: name price contact number show but image not show

Comment: Your getting image from a url or a uri?

Comment: i am getting image from uri

Comment: of course there will be an error glide is only used with url not uri

Comment: how i change uri with url ? can you show us

Comment: Sorry i was confused for a second look at my answer

Comment: If it works for you accept the answer please,if it doesn't tell me your errors

Answer (score 0):

You may use picasso instead of glide,

in your build.gradle app

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

then

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(uploadCurrent.getFilePathUri()).into(holder.mimageView);
```

If it didn't work try making sure that `uploadCurrent.getFilePathUri()` returns a valid uri.

if it returns a valid uri then the problem is with the context maybe
try

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uploadCurrent.getFilePathUri()).into(holder.mimageView);
```

if still no luck then the best way is to remove picasso and glide and write

```
holder.imageView.setImageUri(uploadCurrent.getFilePathUri());
```

That's it.